# how to refactor to a different class in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, methods, refactoring

I can refactor a big code to a new method which automatically sets the parameters, return type, if static or not etc in the same class. Is there a way that I can move the code to a new function in a different class if I could specify the class somehow? May be I'm missing something silly.

Comment: Do you want something more automated than Ctrl-X and Ctrl-V?

Comment: @Cody Gray haha, good one. but come on just knowing if there's a faster way :) i use refactor a lot, its more than copy paste..

Comment: @CodyGray well, if you're going to be doing a paste, it's safer to do a copy and paste rather than cut and paste, so Ctrl-C,  and gradually change the references to the method so they refer to the new one,  so as to make the original version redundant. .. And there's no need to do a ctrl-x and get a load of errors in your code to fix,  when you can do a Ctrl-C and avoid that and then refactor it under less pressure. Anyhow, the whole Ctrl- whatever and Ctrl-V isn't ideal, as nawfal says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VIsual Studio there is no possibility to move methods between classes. But if you use ReSharper from JetBrains, you can move static methods between classes with Move To Another Type command.